# How to get the all likes of post with out getting the pagaing in json response given by Graph api in one single json call?

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, restfb, facebook4j

I'm trying to get the all the likes of the a post by using the Graph api.I'm able to get only the 1000 likes in json response and the other likes data is in the paging obj next link.How can i break that paging to get all the post likes of the post in one single Graph api call.

[image]

Comment: use a recursive function to get all entries with the paging object. there is no way to always get all entries otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `limit` parameter and set it to a desired value, but you should have this sentence from the Facebook Graph API Reference in mind:

> Some edges have an upper maximum on the `limit` value, for performance reasons. We will return the correct pagination links if that happens.

if you use RestFB you simply have to work with the `Connection` object and check the manual how to use it. But I guess you don't want to do multiple calls to fetch all your likes? Do you run into some limits?